# Dudas con el Manejo de la memoria en JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, eventos, manejo-de-memoria

he estado leyendo sobre el manejo de la memoria en JAVA y hay preguntas que no he podido resolver, un ejemplo claro, tengo un código que se ejecuta dos veces y no entiendo el porqué, lo único que he podido identificar es que se trata de el manejo de la memoria en JAVA.

Tuve que colocarle un JOPTIONPANE que lo renombré

```
Mensaje.getMensajeWAR("");
```

Lo anterior lo hice para buscar otro error, pero por sorpresa me di cuenta que el método se ejecuta dos veces. Este es mi método.

```
public List<Conductor> getConductores() throws SQLException {
    List<Conductor> conductores = new LinkedList<>();
    consulta = " SELECT c_cedula, c_nombre, c_huella FROM conductor ";
    try {
        Mensaje.getMensajeWAR("MENSAJE DE EJECUCION");
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(consulta);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            conductores.add(new Conductor(rs.getLong("c_cedula"), rs.getString("c_nombre"), rs.getBytes("c_huella")));
        }
        connection.close();
        return conductores;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Mensaje.getMensajeERR("EXCEPCION SQL En el metodo getConductores en ControladorConductor.java: " + ex.getMessage());
        EscritorFichero.enviarLog("EXCEPCION SQL En el metodo getConductores en ControladorConductor.java: " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (this.connection != null && !this.connection.isClosed()) {
            this.connection.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Para tener un poco mas claro el contexto, este método está dentro de un Process:

```
class Progress extends SwingWorker<Integer, String> {
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
        try {
            JFrame_CargandoBasico cargando = new JFrame_CargandoBasico();
            cargando.setVisible(true);

            Usuario u = new ControladorUsuario().getUsuario(txtUsuarioLogin.getText().toUpperCase(), String.valueOf(txtClaveLogin.getPassword()).toUpperCase());

            if (u != null) {
                cargando.setVisible(false);
                JFrame_CargandoConductores cargandoConductores = new JFrame_CargandoConductores();
                cargandoConductores.setVisible(true);
                List<Conductor> conductores = new ControladorConductor().getConductores();
                cargandoConductores.setVisible(false);
                List<Limite> limites = new ControladorLimite().getLimites();
                VentanaPrincipal ventanaPrincipal = new VentanaPrincipal(conductores, u, limites);
                ventanaPrincipal.setVisible(true);
                cargando.dispose();
                cargandoConductores.dispose();
                done();
                dispose();
            } else {
                EscritorFichero.enviarLogInfo("Error de Autenticacion o de Permisos");
                cargando.dispose();
                Mensaje.getMensajeWAR("Usuario y/o clave son invalidos");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Mensaje.getMensajeERR("EXCEPCION en el FORMULARIO JFrameCargando dentro de un process: " + e);
        }
        return Integer.valueOf(0);
    }
}
```

El cual ejecuto con un botón de hacer login de la siguiente manera.

```
private void btnIngresarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    Progress p = new Progress();
    p.execute();
}
```

Comment: Dónde está el problema con el manejo de la memoria?

Comment: No se entiende cuál es el problema en tu pregunta. Dices que hay un método que se ejecuta dos veces y dices que muestras el contexto, pero no es el contexto completo el cual deberías examinar por ti mismo para saber a qué se debe el que se ejecute dos veces. El método `btnIngresarActionPerformed()` por ejemplo no lo pones en su contexto, por lo tanto no puede verse qué ocurre antes o después. En los otros fragmentos de código también hay otros métodos e instancias de clases que se crean. Cualquier de ellos podria estar llamando también al método que dices que se ejecuta dos veces.